# How to interpret Result of two way anova test in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, anova

```
m1 <- lm(AmountSpent~Catalogs*Salary,data=d) 
summary(m1)
m2<-lm(AmountSpent~Catalogs+Salary,data=d)
summary(m2)

anova(m2,m1,test="Chisq")
```

The output is as follows 
[image]

What is the better model according to test ? Is the order in which we insert models in the method important? Please explain the statistical concept behind this test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chi-square test looks into the statistical significance in reduction of the residual sum of squares between the nested linear models. From your R ouput you can see that adding a term to the regression resulted statistically in a better model (the one with the lower RSS value, Model 2).

It is usual to start the comparing with a simpler model and then add terms, however, the docs also mention that it is up to the user.

You should take a look at the docs of the the `anova.lm` function [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/anova.lm.html).

For comparing models that are not nested rather use AIC or BIC criteria.